# Form Alignment input and drop downs

Tags: html, css, forms, alignment

How could I align my input boxes so that the first one is aligned with the label and the other two is aligned underneath the top input box.

Why is my domain and dropdown menu not aligning?

CSS:

```
#newwebsiteForm{
    padding:10px;
    margin:10px 0;
    width:480px;
    position: relative
}
#newwebsiteForm label{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    margin:0 15px 0 25px;
    width:240px;
    border:1px solid green;
    height:15px
}
#newwebsiteForm input{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:240px;
    height:15px;
}
#newwebsiteForm .radioButton {
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
}
#newwebsiteForm .radioText {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:20px;
    float:left;
    font-size:12px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
#newwebsiteForm #color1,#color2,#color3,#fav1,#fav2,#fav3{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin-left:25px;
    background-color:red;
}
#newwebsiteForm textarea{
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
input#domain,#newwebsiteForm select,
.form-field{float:right;width:200px;margin-top:-15px}

.form-field{width:220px}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="newwebsiteSection">
                                    <form action="#" id="newwebsiteForm" method="get">
                                    <fieldset>  
                                     <div>
                                     <label>Do You Require Hosting?</label>
                                        <span class="radioText">Yes</span><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes"/>
                                        <span class="radioText">No</span><input  class="radioButton" type="radio" name="No" value="No"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                    <label>Do You Require A Domain?</label>
                                        <span class="radioText">Yes</span><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes"/>
                                        <span class="radioText">No</span><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="No" value="No"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <label>Do You Have A Logo?</label>
                                        <span class="radioText">Yes</span><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes"/>
                                        <span class="radioText">No</span><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="No" value="No"/>

                                    <label for="domain">What is your Domain?</label>
                                    <input type="url" id="domain" value="http://example.com"/>

                                    <label for="newwebsiteType">Type of site Required?</label>
                                        <select name="newwebsiteType" id="newwebsiteType">
                                        <option value="shoppingCart">Shopping Cart</option>
                                        <option value="CMS">Content Management System</option>
                                        <option value="static">Static Website</option>
                                        <option value="otherDevelopment">Other Development</option>
                                    </select>

                                    <label>Do You Require A Design?</label>
                                        <span class="radioText">Yes</span><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes"/>
                                        <span class="radioText">No</span><input class="radioButton" type="radio" name="No" value="No"/>


                                    <div>
                                        <label>Three Favorite colors?</label>
                                        <div class="form-field">
                                            <input id="color1" value=""/>
                                            <input id="color2" value=""/>
                                            <input id="color3" value=""/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                    <label>What are your favorite websites?</label>
                                    <div class="form-field">
                                        <input type="text" id="fav1" value=""/>
                                        <input type="text" id="fav2" value=""/>
                                        <input type="text" id="fav3" value=""/>
                                    </div>    
            </div>
                                    <label for="comments">Comments?</label>
                                    <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>

                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Quote Request"/>
                                    </fieldset>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: The text-align css property may help you greatly:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the flack they've gotten lately, I feel like this is one of the few examples of where a `table` is actually not only useful, but the most correct solution.